# Convert string to datetime SQLServer2008

Tags: java, database, sql-server-2008, date

I have `26062012` format.
I want convert this format to `datetime` in SQL Server 2008.

My code is:

```
else if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("DATETIME")){
    sb.append("CONVERT(Datetime,'").append(strCell).append("',102)").append(',');
}
```

Error is :

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The conversion of a 
  varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

Comment: First things first: do not use string concatenation to build SQL queries, use prepared statements. Libraries to do this in Java abound, you have no reason not to use one.

Answer (score 0):

Your date string is missing the dots as seperators between day and month or month and year repectivly.

The `102` format looks like `2012.06.26`.

In order to get your format into a parsable one, I'd suggest, changing your string to

```
String changedDate = yourDate.SubString(0,2)+"."+yourDate.SubString(2,4)+"."+yourDate.SubString(4,8)
```

and use the `104`format.

Also please do as fge has said and use an API to build your queries.

**EDIT**
If you have to convert that same format more often and in multipe applications, you can also build a stored procedure or function in your database like [so](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/).